# How to exclude a single controller action from a filter in Rails 3.07?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, before-filter

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :check_session_expiry, :except => :login
```

How do you exclude a ***single*** controller's (the users controller, for example) login action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_session_expiry


  def check_session_expiry
     return true if self.class != UsersController && self.action == "login"
     # do your thing
  end
```

Answer (score 5):

First, I'm not on a machine with rails to test it, but the following should work:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  skip_filter :check_session_expiry, :only => :foo

  # following is DEPRECATED as far as I know
  #skip_before_filter :check_session_expiry, :only => :foo

  def foo
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just redefine check_session_expiry in your controller to be an empty method.

```
  class UserController < ...
    ...
    private
    def check_session_expire
      # optional if other actions shall still use the filter
      super unless self.action == 'login'
    end
  end
```

Comment: But what's with the other controller actions? The filter than did not run for those. OP just want to skip the filter for one action only.

Comment: Sorry I thought he wanted the filter removed completely.